# What do "a.m." and "p.m." stand for when talking about time?

Tags: meaning

What do a.m. and p.m. stand for when talking about time?

Comment: I think this is easily answered by resources such as wikipedia.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are from the Latin for *ante meridiem* and *post meridiem*, which mean "before noon" and after noon", respectively.

Comment: It is worth mentioning the crazy gotcha involving 12am and 12pm. 12pm means _noon_ and 12:30pm is the half hour _after noon_. 12am means _midnight_. Many, many, many people get this incorrect.

Comment: @MrHen; The confusion is usually caused by the fact that 11am is directly followed by 12pm, or 12pm is directly followed by 1pm, rather than that 12:30pm follows 12:00pm. But otherwise you're correct, it's a common mistake. :)

Comment: @all: Probably flirting with off-topicism here (I only got here from a link on *Discussion re trivial questions*), but I think MrHen's point could well be useful to a number of future 'seekers after knowledge' who might not have realised they were in danger of getting it wrong, and therefore might not have actively sought the additional info. In short, I don't see why OP should be rejected as 'trivial'.

Comment: Trying deperately to stay on-topic, I'll just say the standard rule is **Midnight belongs to the new day**, and woe betide any programmers, schedulers, etc. who get that wrong (but a surprising number *do*).

Comment: The confusion between 12am and 12pm is sufficiently commonplace that legal documents often use times like 12:01pm to make it clear. For example: All contest entries must be received by 12:01pm on April 1, 2012 to be considered.

Comment: If you're worried about confusion, you can just say *12 noon* or *12 midnight.*

Comment: @Wayne Johnston: how does it help?